# Effect that detects white object throughout entire video and blurs it, without manually running tracking mask?

Tags: premiere, adobe, effects, tracking

Is there a way to track an easily identifiable white object that appears in every frame of a video and apply an effect like blur to the space it occupies for every frame that it appears?

In Adobe Premiere Pro, the object would have to be manually *selected* in its first appearance, and from there you apply a tracking mask for the blur effect for one entire run through the video to track it all the way through to the last frame,

but I'm instead looking for a tracker that does not have to be manually attached. Instead it should detect the patch of white, or white object, automatically for every frame that it appears, and applies the effect to each detected frame wherever the object is located at that time.

The object is distinctive in color  against the different-colored background and other objects in the video because of its solid color, and moves to different positions each frame (not fixed in one place), that's why it should be possible somehow maybe by **color detection**

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Color detection, when you’re looking for a white object is really the same thing as what’s known as a “luma key.” So, you can try that, but you’ll quickly see why the VFX industry prefers chroma keys. You could try a machine learning based approach, and both Premiere and Davinci Resolve have ML object removal, but it’s less automatic, and more error prone than you’d expect, and requires certain conditions to be successful at all. Of course, the state of the art is advancing quickly, and this could change in the near future.

Comment: What is ML object removal called in Premiere and Davinci Resolve?

Comment: In Resolve, it’s just called “object removal”. If memory serves, it’s called “content aware fill” in Premiere.